# Easy plot, but I'm stuck

Tags: plotting, functions

I'm literally trying to plot this basic function, I know my problems in Mathematica always come down to simple syntax errors..

```
Clear[f, x, k]
f[x_] = x^2 + kx;
Plot[[f[x], {x, 0, 10}, {k, 0, 10}]]
```

"the expression f[x] cannot be used as a part specification "

I cant wait to see how simple this is...

Comment: You used double brackets instead of single. You didn't put a space between k and x. You used Plot instead of Plot3D.

Comment: I should've known about the k*x part, oops. Thanks for the rest of the clarification @SimonWoods

Comment: you also used Set instead of SetDelayed